# Make a Text with dynamic number of lines

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have a `Text` inside a height specified `Container`. I want to make a `Text` widget that satisfy these 2 conditions but don't know how:

1. If the text is too long I want it to keep breaking to next line as long as it is not overflowing out of container.
2. If the text is too long to be displayed all inside `Container` then I still want the `Text` widget to expand as much as possible and replace some last displayed character with ellipsis.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround:

```
final loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
  double containerHeight = 20.0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("building first");

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
      child: Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      height: containerHeight,
      width: 100,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            TextStyle currentTextStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1;
            int maxLines = ((constraints.maxHeight / currentTextStyle.fontSize) * 0.8).floor();
            maxLines = maxLines > 0 ? maxLines : 1;
            return new Text(
              loremIpsum,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: maxLines,
              style: currentTextStyle,
            );
          }),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is an [open](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15465) ticket in their framework and from there I got most of the answer.

And the results:

[image]
[image]
[image]